# Как правильно оформить задание?

Tags: оформление-текста

Как правильно оформить это задание?

> Найдите слова, неправильно написанные в этом фрагменте песни «День, который жду», и перепишите таковые правильно.

> 1. У памети нет слов она из немых снов, она как стон из уст немых в мыслях моих. И все таки я рад на миг воскресить взгляд любимых глаз, не видя их.

> 2. У памяти нет слов, она из немых снов, / Она как стон из уст немых в мыслях моих. / И все-таки я рад на миг воскресить взгляд / Любимых глаз, не видя их.

Comment: Я рекомендую аоабские цифры заменить на римские — именно такие были в моем учебнике.

Comment: Лео, а можно перейти на нейтральный стиль речи. И чтобы слова правильно писать: с орфографией. // Зачем здесь прилагательное "небезынтересный"? Информационной нагрузки у него нет.

Comment: *Ю* тоже можно использовать.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр ваш специфический лексикон будьте добры использовать в рамках цитирования текста, вызывающего у вас затруднения. Сами вопросы к аудитории форума правильно будет писать современным русским общепринятым языком. Форумчане не книгу вашу приходят сюда почитать, а помочь таким, как вы, с вопросами. И "небезынтересный" у вас вопрос или какой ещё – больше вредит.  Ваш вопрос отредактировал. После "жду", кстати, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Вообще-то нужна! Кто будет оборот, который начинается с *неправильно написанные*, обособлять?